# Two Powershell strings of different lengths are considered equal?

Tags: string, powershell, hidden-characters

I have found something unusual with PowerShell strings...I hope this is just something I'm missing.  Here's what I found.

I copied some data from a web page (KQL searches for O365 if anyone cares), and it contained hidden control characters.  Here are the two lines as I stored them in PowerShell variables:

```
PS C:\Users> $L1 = "(c:c)(date=01/01/2014..11/01/2016)"
PS C:\Users> $L2 = "(c:c)‎‎(date=01/01/2014..11/01/2016)‎"
```

The second line has two hidden characters (Unicode character 8206) between the "(c:c)" and the "(date".  I believe they are still there in this post.  Because of this, the two strings have different lengths:

```
PS C:\Users> $L1.Length
34

PS C:\Users> $L2.Length
36
```

And yet, when I check to see if they are equal to each other, PowerShell tells me they are:

```
PS C:\Users> $L1 -eq $L2
True
```

Now, I know it understands that there are differences there.  I can use the substring method to pull out some characters, and show that the substrings are not equal:

```
PS C:\Users> $L1.Substring(4,8)
)(date=0

PS C:\Users> $L2.Substring(4,8)
)‎‎(date
```

If I use the -eq operator to compare those substrings, I get the correct answer:

```
PS C:\Users> $L1.Substring(4,8) -eq $L2.Substring(4,8)
False
```

But if I force the strings to **display** the same by changing how many characters I grab so I get the same 6 visible characters, then PowerShell will tell me that they are equal:

```
PS C:\Users> $L1.Substring(4,6)
)(date

PS C:\Users> $L2.Substring(4,8)
)‎‎(date

PS C:\Users> $L1.Substring(4,6) -eq $L2.Substring(4,8)
True
```

So, is this expected behavior?  Am I missing something?  I've been programming long enough that I know string handling can be weird...but this is beyond my personal experience.

If it is expected behavior, how to I properly compare two string variables to see if they are exactly the same?

Comment: `[String]::Equals($L1, $L2, 'Ordinal')`

Comment: [`[String]::Equals($L1, $L2, "Ordinal")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t4411bks). Try `"CurrentCulture"` or `"InvariantCulture"` instead to see a culture-sensitive comparison.

Comment: Appreciate the working answer, however it leaves me with the question of why the $L1 -eq $L2 is returning true.  Is that because it is doing something similar to the "CurrentCulture" or "InvariantCulture" comparisons?  How can I function if I can't trust something as simple as $L1 -eq $L2 will return a ... simple ... answer?  :)

Comment: Apparently `$L2` contains 3 "left-to-right-mark" characters (U+200e) which seem to be ignored in the comparison. This probably has to do with what Jon Skeet ranted abou^W^Wdiscussed in his legendary ["OMG Ponies!!!" talk](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/) on the 2009 DevDays.